# How to join two queries in Sybase using right join?

Tags: sql, sybase, sqlanywhere, right-join

I got a problem in joining two queries. Can someone please check my code?

The first query should get patient data

- tx_plans
- provider_ids
- providers
- ng_rest_prod
- insurance
- invis_ortho_codes
- thirds_implants
- next_visit

```
        SELECT
          b.patient_id,
          LIST(a.service_code, ', ' ORDER BY a.service_code) AS tx_plans,
          b.provider_id AS provider_ids,
          (d.last_name + ', ' + d.first_name) AS providers,
          '' AS ng_rest_prod,
          NULL AS insurance,
          '' AS invis_ortho_codes,
          '' AS thirds_implants,
          NULL AS next_visit
        FROM 
          transactions_header a 
          INNER JOIN transactions_detail b 
            ON a.tran_num = b.tran_num
          INNER JOIN 
          (
            SELECT  
              SUBSTRING(row_value,0,CHARINDEX('_',row_value)) AS tran_num, 
              SUBSTRING(row_value,CHARINDEX('_',row_value)+1,LENGTH(row_value)) AS eod_date
            FROM sa_split_list('914561_2020-08-03,914562_2020-08-03,914563_2020-08-03,914564_2020-08-03,914565_2020-08-03')
          ) c 
            ON a.tran_num = c.tran_num
                    INNER JOIN provider d 
            ON b.provider_id = d.provider_id
        WHERE 1 = 1 
          AND a.impacts = 'P'
          AND eod_date BETWEEN DATEFORMAT('2020-08-24 00:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-01') AND '2020-08-24 00:00:00'
        GROUP BY b.patient_id, b.provider_id, providers
```

The second query should show new patients data

- patient_id
- patient_name
- age

```
       SELECT 
          b.patient_id,
          (d.last_name + ', ' + d.first_name) AS patient_name,
          FLOOR(DATEDIFF(DAY, d.birth_date,  TODAY(*))/365) AS age
        FROM
          transactions_header a 
          INNER JOIN transactions_detail b 
          ON a.tran_num = b.tran_num 
                    INNER JOIN 
          (
            SELECT  
              SUBSTRING(row_value,0,CHARINDEX('_',row_value)) AS tran_num, 
              SUBSTRING(row_value,CHARINDEX('_',row_value)+1,LENGTH(row_value)) AS eod_date
            FROM sa_split_list('914561_2020-08-03,914562_2020-08-03,914563_2020-08-03,914564_2020-08-03,914565_2020-08-03')
          ) c 
          ON a.tran_num = c.tran_num
        INNER JOIN patient d
          ON b.patient_id = d.patient_id
        WHERE a.impacts = 'P'
          AND eod_date BETWEEN DATEFORMAT('2020-08-24 00:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-01') AND '2020-08-24 00:00:00'

                    AND d.first_visit_date BETWEEN DATEFORMAT('2020-08-24 00:00:00', 'YYYY-mm-01') AND '2020-08-24 00:00:00'
          AND a.tran_date = d.first_visit_date


        GROUP BY b.patient_id, patient_name, d.birth_date.
```

Query's output should be new patients together with its data.

It returns `Invalid expression near 'b.provider_id = d.provider_id'`

Here's the code I implemented

```
    SELECT
      b.patient_id,
      b.patient_name AS patient_name,
      b.age AS age,
      LIST(DISTINCT(a.tx_plans)) AS tx_plans,
      LIST(
        DISTINCT(
            CASE
              WHEN a.provider_ids IS NOT NULL
              THEN a.provider_ids
              ELSE ''
            END
          )
        ) AS provider_ids,
      LIST(
        DISTINCT(
            CASE
              WHEN a.providers IS NOT NULL
              THEN a.providers
              ELSE ''
            END
          )
        ) AS providers,
      SUM(ng_rest_prod) AS ng_rest_prod,
      LIST(a.insurance, ', ' ORDER BY a.insurance) AS insurance,
      LIST(DISTINCT(a.invis_ortho_codes)) AS invis_ortho_codes,
      LIST(DISTINCT(a.thirds_implants)) AS thirds_implants,
      LIST(a.next_visit) AS next_visit
    FROM
      (
        SELECT
          b.patient_id,
          LIST(a.service_code, ', ' ORDER BY a.service_code) AS tx_plans,
          b.provider_id AS provider_ids,
          (d.last_name + ', ' + d.first_name) AS providers,
          '' AS ng_rest_prod,
          NULL AS insurance,
          '' AS invis_ortho_codes,
          '' AS thirds_implants,
          NULL AS next_visit
        FROM 
          transactions_header a 
          INNER JOIN transactions_detail b 
            ON a.tran_num = b.tran_num
          INNER JOIN 
          (
            SELECT  
              SUBSTRING(row_value,0,CHARINDEX('_',row_value)) AS tran_num, 
              SUBSTRING(row_value,CHARINDEX('_',row_value)+1,LENGTH(row_value)) AS eod_date
            FROM sa_split_list('914561_2020-08-03,914562_2020-08-03,914563_2020-08-03,914564_2020-08-03,914565_2020-08-03')
          ) c 
            ON a.tran_num = c.tran_num
                    INNER JOIN provider d 
            ON b.provider_id = d.provider_id
        WHERE 1 = 1 
          AND a.impacts = 'P'
          AND eod_date BETWEEN DATEFORMAT('2020-08-24 00:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-01') AND '2020-08-24 00:00:00'
        GROUP BY b.patient_id, b.provider_id, providers
      ) AS a 

      RIGHT JOIN 
      (
        SELECT 
          b.patient_id,
          (d.last_name + ', ' + d.first_name) AS patient_name,
          FLOOR(DATEDIFF(DAY, d.birth_date,  TODAY(*))/365) AS age
        FROM
          transactions_header a 
          INNER JOIN transactions_detail b 
          ON a.tran_num = b.tran_num 
                    INNER JOIN 
          (
            SELECT  
              SUBSTRING(row_value,0,CHARINDEX('_',row_value)) AS tran_num, 
              SUBSTRING(row_value,CHARINDEX('_',row_value)+1,LENGTH(row_value)) AS eod_date
            FROM sa_split_list('914561_2020-08-03,914562_2020-08-03,914563_2020-08-03,914564_2020-08-03,914565_2020-08-03')
          ) c 
          ON a.tran_num = c.tran_num
        INNER JOIN patient d
          ON b.patient_id = d.patient_id
        WHERE a.impacts = 'P'
          AND eod_date BETWEEN DATEFORMAT('2020-08-24 00:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-01') AND '2020-08-24 00:00:00'
          
                    AND d.first_visit_date BETWEEN DATEFORMAT('2020-08-24 00:00:00', 'YYYY-mm-01') AND '2020-08-24 00:00:00'
          AND a.tran_date = d.first_visit_date
           
                               
        GROUP BY b.patient_id, patient_name, d.birth_date
      ) b
        ON a.patient_id = b.patient_id
  GROUP BY b.patient_id, patient_name, age
```

Comment: I have no idea what the query has to do with the question.

Comment: I got a problem in joining the two queries. I tried to run the first and second query and it was successful. But when I tried to join them, it returns `Invalid expression near 'b.provider_id = d.provider_id'`

Comment: which Sybase RDBMS product (ASE? IQ? SQLAnywhere? Advantage?) and version?

Comment: @markp-fuso Sybase Adaptive Server Anywhere

Comment: Note: `DISTINCT coalesce(a.providers, '') AS providers` will avoid the case-expression.